# Twig: functional test differences 1.28.2 & 1.30.0

Tags: php, twig, symfony

After copying an app's source code from a working Symfony 2.8.15 installation to a new Symfony 3.2 project and running functional tests there is a difference between the two in rendering:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    {{ form_row(form.center) }}
</div>
```

2.8: Twig 1.28.2, Twig/extensions: 1.0.1
3.2: Twig 1.30.0, Twig/extensions: 1.4.1

This causes differences in the evaluation of:

```
$crawler->filter("#household_center option:selected")->text()
```

in 2.8 there are not added spaces, in 3.2 there are quite a few. The tests can be modified by using:

```
$centerText = trim($crawler->filter("#household_center option:selected")->text());
```

but I wonder what other differences there are that aren't mentioned in an UPGRADE or CHANGELOG notice. [FWIW, the twig entries in config.yml are identical.]

In 2.8 this is rendered as

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="household_center">Site:</label><select     id="household_center" name="household[center]"         disabled="disabled" class="form-control"><option  value="">Select site</option><option value="819">Incline Village</option><option value="817" selected="selected">Kings Beach</option><option value="816">Tahoe City</option><option value="818">Truckee</option></select></div>
```

In 3.2 it is rendered as

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="household_center">Site:</label><select     id="household_center" name="household[center]"         disabled="disabled" class="form-control"><option  value="">Select site</option><option value="607"
                                                    >
                    Incline Village
                </option><option value="605"
                         selected="selected"                            >
                    Kings Beach
                </option><option value="604"
                                                    >
                    Tahoe City
                </option><option value="606"
                                                    >
                    Truckee
                </option></select></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake! The difference arises due to `braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle`. After changing it to `dev-develop` to get rid of a deprecation notice, the rendering of bootstrap changes.  Not nice.